# what is a simple way to run many similar queries concurrently in SQLite in c++?

Tags: c++, sqlite

There are many threads in my program, and they simply run queries like "select content from table where id= xxx".

I first planned to provide a `db_query(int id)` function with a static `sqlite3` object and a static `sqlite3_stmt` object which stands for the query. So all the threads can call this function and get results.

But then I find that the `sqlite3_stmt` object is not stateless and cannot be used by many threads. In addition, there seems not a function provided for copying a `sqlite3_stmt` object, so I cannot just make a copy of the prepared statement in each function call.

Is there an elite and easy-to-implement way to solve my problem?

Comment: SQLite [threading](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html).

Comment: Another SQLite doc note (from faq): https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6

Comment: I usually have a separate connection for each thread, opened in what sqlite calls multi-thread mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. "There are many threads in my program,"  This suggests that you would do best to rethink your design.  You current design is going to trip you up over and over again.  However, using your current design:
2. You will need to create a new sqlite3_stmt for each query.  Change it from static to automatic, so it will be created each time db_query(int id) is called.
3. You cannot run queries "concurrently".  You have to do them one at a time.  So you will need to protect you query code with a mutex.